Check if an account is a program
So in anchor we can enforce that a provided account is the system program, the token program, or the associated token program using the following constraint.
my_program: Program<'info, System>
As far as I understand, the check here is just using the program id. Is there a way we can more generically check if a provided account is a program?

Solana accounts store some extra metadata beside the raw bytes (which is also why an empty account costs rent!):

In our case, the interesting one is the executable boolean which specifies wether the account code can be executed i.e. if this account is a program. We can check it using my_account.executable or enforce it using the #[account(executable)] constraint in anchor.

The picture is taken from https://solana.com/docs/core/accounts#accountinfo
